# Why does AJAX not process login form?

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I am writing a simple login script in PHP with a form. But can't get it to work. There is probably something wrong with my AJAX. When i click the submit button it doesn't do anything.

This is my login HTML form:

```
<form id="login_form">
            <input type="text" class="input_field" name="username" id="username" value="gebruikersnaam" onclick="if(value=='gebruikersnaam'){ this.value='' }"/>
            <input type="password" class="input_field" name="password" id="password"/>
            <input type="submit" class="login_button" id="login_button" value="Ga door"/>
        </form>
```

This is my AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#login_form").submit(function() {

     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'php/login_check.php',
           data: $("#login_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           succes: function(logincheck) {
                if (logincheck == 'true') {alert ("Succes");}
                else {alert ("Failed");}
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
});
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'config.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Check for credentials
$Credentials_Query = mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Registered_Users WHERE Username='$username' AND password='$password'"); 

$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($Credentials_Query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($Credentials_Query);
if( $num_row >= 1 ) { 
echo 'true';
$_SESSION['username_session']=$row['Username'];
}
else {
echo 'false';
}
?>
```

I know this is really basic stuff. Still I can't get it to work. Don't know what I'm missing...?

Comment: open up developer tools and click on the 'Network' tab.. do you see the request actually going out when you submit the form?

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: succes spelling is wrong it should be success

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Don't abuse the default value as one.

Comment: @Watcher, Yes the request goes out. The PHP script works as expected. Outputs 'true' when credentials are correct.

Comment: You're writing a login form but don't know enough to prevent sql injection or avoid plaintext passwords!  Stop!  Do not pass go!  Instead, use someone else's open source & heavily vetted login system library!  Learn how they do it first.  Do not wing authentication, it won't end well.  http://www.php-login.net/ just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelt `success` as `succes`.

Comment: "Misspelt" is British English (the original), and "misspelled" is an American adaption. lol Depends on where you're from I guess ;)

Comment: In my language we spell 'success' as 'succes'. With one 's' at the end. So that's where the spelling mistake came from ;-)

Comment: @NvdB31 I'd call that an "honest" mistake ;) yet, syntax is not the same, unfortunately.